# Two MySQL docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have a server that already run a MySQL server container on port `3306:3306` (build from a `docker-compose.yml` file)

I would like to run another MySQL container on port `3307:3306` from another `docker-compose.yml`. The problem is that for the second container the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` is never set and I got an access denied.

Both containers are targeting different volumes.

Is it possible to run two MySQL container from two different `docker-compose.yml` file on the same server?

Comment: The setup you've described should work fine.  Do you have a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?  Do you have the same problem if you just start only the port-3307 database, without the port-3306 database?

Answer (score 1):

You are able to run 2 instances of MySQL on the same host and they don't interfere with each other.

What I think is causing your issue is that the environment variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` (and other environment variables) is only used when the container is started witout an existing database. If a database already exists, then the root password stored in the database is used.

You need to find out what root password was set when the database was created and use that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

`docker-compose.yml` doesn't accept `env` variable with the char `$`. To solve it we must escape the char like this : `$$`.

Thanks for your help guys.